# Write dictionary results from one FOR loop to JSON file

Tags: python, json

Title might be misleading, I can't think of a better way to say it :(.

I am trying to write **dictionary** keys and values to a JSON file in JSON format.

Example:

```
{
    key1: value1
    key2: value1
},

{
    key1: value2
    key2: value2
}
```

And so on and so on.

I am trying to achieve this result inside a FOR loop.

Here is the current code I have:

```py
for row in CSVR:
    if totalCSV == 0:
        # Not important for this question
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(row[0], "html.parser") # Parsing results from CSV file using BeautifulSoup

        confirmationNumber = remover(getConfirmationNumber(soup)) # Get confirmation number from a person
        answersQuestions = remover(getQuestionsAndAnswers(soup)) # Get their question

        answersQuestions = answersQuestions.strip() # Strip leading or trailing spaces

        aa = {
        "Confirmation Number": confirmationNumber,
        "Message": answersQuestions
        }

        with open(bdPath, "w") as f:
            json.dump(aa, f, indent = 4) # Write to JSON file
```

**aa** is a dictionary I am working with. Variables **confirmationNumber** and **answersQuestions** change depending on FOR loop.

In a file I am writing the results, I get only the last result from the FOR loop instead of all of them.

How can I fix this and/or make this code better if there is a way?

Comment: ***" I get only the last result from the FOR loop"***: Move `with open(...` block outside the `for row ...` loop and make `aa` a `list` of `dict`.

Comment: @stovfl What do you mean by list of dict? Something like [{key1: value1}]?

Comment: ***"Something like [{key1: value1}]?"***: Yes, see the answer of @Maurice Meyer

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the JSON file after the loop and keep track of `aa` by 'storing' them in a list:

```
results = []
for row in CSVR:
    if totalCSV == 0:
        # Not important for this question
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(row[0], "html.parser") # Parsing results from CSV file using BeautifulSoup

        confirmationNumber = remover(getConfirmationNumber(soup)) # Get confirmation number from a person
        answersQuestions = remover(getQuestionsAndAnswers(soup)) # Get their question

        answersQuestions = answersQuestions.strip() # Strip leading or trailing spaces

        results.append({
            "Confirmation Number": confirmationNumber,
            "Message": answersQuestions
        })

with open(bdPath, "w") as f:
    json.dump(results, f, indent = 4) # Write to JSON file
```

Comment: Please, explain the requirement of a `list` of `dict` also.